# What non random patterns in a series Autocorrelation cannot detect

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I know there are complex patterns in a series that cannot be detected by autocorrelation... but I cannot find what types of patterns these are. Can anyone provide an instance where the autocorrelation does not pick up on a pattern or provide a link to a site that provides examples of this?

Comment: Autocorrelation, being a function of just first and second moments of the multivariate distribution, has the same limitations as correlations in any bivariate distribution.  The classical set of examples is given by [Anscombe's quartet](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=anscombe+quartet).

Comment: What about for non random time series, where the autocorrelation plot is looking for a pattern in the response variable with the y-axis being the autocorrelation and the x-axis being the lag.

Comment: The regular patterns will show up in autocorrelation plots.

Comment: Randomness is irrelevant: the computation and interpretation of moments is the same regardless.  The "one aspect" referred to in your Google Books reference specifically means the first and second order behavior.